# How to commit a SQLite transaction in C/C++?

Tags: c++, sql, c, sqlite, transactions

I am using sqlite c/c++ interface.

I have 3 tables (related tables) say A, B, C. Now, there is a function called **Set**, which get some inputs and based on the inputs inserts rows into these three tables. (sometimes it can be an update in one of the tables)

Now I need two things. One, i dont want autocommit feature. Basically I would like to commit after every 1000 calls to **Set** function

Secondly, within the set function itself, if i find that after inserting into two tables, the third insert fails, then i have to revert, those particular changes in that **Set** function call.

Now i don't see any sqlite3_commit function exposed. I only see a function called sqlite3_commit_hook() which is slightly diff in documentation.

Are there any function exposed for this purpose? or What is the way to achieve this behaviour?

Can you help me with the best approach of doing this.

Comment: can't you just execute `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` queries?

Answer (score 48):

You use [sqlite3_exec](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) and pass "BEGIN TRANSACTION" and "END TRANSACTION" respectively.

```
// 'db' is the pointer you got from sqlite3_open*
sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN TRANSACTION;", NULL, NULL, NULL);
// Any (modifying) SQL commands executed here are not committed until at the you call:
sqlite3_exec(db, "END TRANSACTION;", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

There are synonyms for these SQL commands (like `COMMIT` instead of `END TRANSACTION`). For reference, here is the [SQLite documentation for transactions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).

Comment: Shoule we use `END TRANSACTION` or `COMMIT`?

Comment: They are identical. `END TRANSACTION` is just an alias for `COMMIT` - https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html

Comment: @IsakSavo Will this work if I have to prepare multiple statements, step them and destroy them with finalize between the 'BEGIN TRANSACTION' and 'END TRANSACTION'. I am having multiple insert statement and I want reduce the number of disk IO operations safely.