# c++ sqlite3 update query not commiting

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm learning how to use sqlite3 library for c++ and so far so good I managed to execute SELECT queries and create new tables, but it seems that updating / inserting doesn't work:

As a mock test, I'm using a static query (not using variables):

```
int rc {0};
char *zErrMsg {0};
sql = "UPDATE tag_list set name = 'foo' where ID=16; " \
      "SELECT * from tag_list";

rc = sqlite3_exec(this->db_ptr, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);

if( rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
} else {
    fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
}
```

My callback function is:

```
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
   int i;
   fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", (const char*)data);

   for(i = 0; i<argc; i++) {
      printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
id = 14
name = computer
last_update = 123

id = 16
name = foo
last_update = 1

Operation done successfully
```

When I query the db directly this is what i get:

```
╔════╦══════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║   name   ║ Last_update ║
╠════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 14 ║ computer ║         123 ║
║ 16 ║ s        ║           1 ║
╚════╩══════════╩═════════════╝
```

I checked using sqlite3_get_autocommit and it returned 1, which from what I understood, means it is auto-committing.

I can update rows from the outside, it just happens in the code.

**tl;dr: I'm trying to update a name inside a table I created, but it seems that the change is not commited.**

I hope someone with more experience encountered this before and know how to bypass this.

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880149/how-to-commit-a-sqlite-transaction-in-c-c (`BEGIN TRANSACTION`, `END TRANSACTION`)

Comment: Yes, sadly it didn't help

Comment: You are running two SQL statements in one query. SQLite unfortunately does not allow that. You need to run your _two_ statements in _two_ queries. You have a look for information here http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to find my problem, it is not in the code posted at all..

My problem was that I passed my sqlite3 pointer to another class, thinking it was by reference and not a copy.

The code form above is from my other class in which I can query for data, but not write / change.

As mentioned in SQLite3 documentation (https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html):

> Only one process at a time can hold a RESERVED lock. But other processes can continue to read the database while the RESERVED lock is held.

Code:

main.cpp:

```
in main() {
 sqlite3 *db_ptr;
 sqlite3_open("test.db",db_ptr);

 ConfigurationManager *config_manager = new ConfigurationManager(db_ptr);
}
```

ConfigurationManager.cpp:

```
ConfigurationManager::ConfigurationManager(sqlite3 *db) {
    std::cout << "in constructor" << std::endl;
    this->db_ptr = db;

    if (initialize_db()) {  // initialize_db() creates tables if they don't exist
        std::cout << "Configuration table initialized" << std::endl;
    }


}
int ConfigurationManager::update_rule_last_run(int id) {
    int rc {0};
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    auto epoch = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
    auto epoch_seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(epoch).count();

    std::ostringstream string_stream;
    string_stream << "Update discovery_rules ";
    string_stream << "SET last_run = " << epoch_seconds <<" ";
    string_stream << "Where id = " << id << ";";
    std::string query = string_stream.str();

    std::cout << "- Rule Id " << id << " update command: " << query << std::endl;
    rc = sqlite3_exec(this->db_ptr, query.c_str(), NULL,NULL, &zErrMsg);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        std::cout << "Error occured while polling discovery rules: " << zErrMsg << std::endl;
        throw std::exception();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A possible solution (a one I found) is to create a wrapper class for sqlite3 and manage all queries from it.